# In-app purchase verification: error 401 Insufficient Permissions

Tags: android, curl, oauth-2.0, authorization, token

Consider me a beginner in the dev world.

I am trying to clone my Android app client, but keeping the same server.   So far so good,   but when I reached the in-app purchases part it seems like my server just cannot verify the orders from the cloned new_app package    - error  '401 The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.'

The order itself from the new app goes through. It is just that I verify if it is successful on server side before I give the item.

I am (I would like to) using the same webserver ClientID and Secret from both apps (why should I need separate ones?),   and I suspect that corresponding access token generated which I pass in the curl URL is just not accepted for the new_app case:

```
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.new_app_package/purchases/products/' . $sku . '/tokens/' . $purchaseToken . '?access_token=' . $token, ....
```

Is there some strict linkage between the webserver client / service account and the app package which I miss? I've been struggling already weeks with this dilema with no results... Hints will be appreciated

As I side note: I have given Editor rights to the service account  (GoogleApis IAM);   also I have given the service account emails the 'Full' rights to the app in google play console   (settings/apiaccess+userpermissions)    - no results